# Vlookup equation

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

If you have a date in col1, a name in col2 of sheet1, can you use a vlookup to search for the name in sheet2 and return the only first date greater if that name in sheet2 has multiple dates?

Comment: You can do that with an array formula.

Comment: What would that array formula look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can nest your vlookup inside an if(countif to make it lookup only if your condition is met.  Whatever you are looking up needs to be in a column to the left of the date.  You will also need to have your list of dates sorted descending.

Here is the formula in the example below:  `IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$6,D2)>1,VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$B$6,2,0),"")`

Formula explanation:
Count the number of time the value of D2 appears in A2:A6.  If it appears more than 1 time, return the value of adjacent cell to the right, otherwise, return blank.

[image]

REVISION

A basic vlookup with an approximate match will work for this. When the match type is set to approximate, it returns the next higher result.

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,E1:F6,2,1)
```

[image]

REVISION #2

In order to omit values that are equal to or lesser than the value in column B, you'll need to use an index/match array.  Enter the formula below and then while your cursor is in the cell, press control+shift+enter.  Excel will then add curly braces around the formula and calculate it as an array and return the answer.

```
=IFNA(INDEX($F$1:$F$6,MATCH(1, ($E$1:$E$6=A1)*($F$1:$F$6>B1),0)),"")
```

Without the IFNA wrapped around the Index/Match formula, if there are no matches with a greater date, Excel will return a #N/A error.  However, it will also return a #N/A error if you don't get the control+shift+enter done correctly.

I recommend you first enter the formula below, which doesn't include the IFNA wrapper, and confirm that some matches are returned.  If your item doesn't have any matches, then #N/A will be returned, but you'll know the formula is working properly. Then change the formula to the one above that does include the IFNA wrapper, so that blanks are returned in place of #N/A.

```
=INDEX($F$1:$F$6,MATCH(1, ($E$1:$E$6=A5)*($F$1:$F$6>B5),0))
```

After the first is done, you can double-click the lower-right corner of the cell to populate the rest of the column.

[image]

Comment: If fred flintstone had two more dates in column E (dates 3/9 and 3/22); I need an equation in C2 to look for the for the first fred flintsone date greater than B2 and in column E and get that return value that value, so I would need 3/9 returned

Comment: So both of your lists have duplicate names?  Or is one of the a list of unique values?

Comment: Yes, from the shot you post, I would need and equation in column C to look for the matching name in column D with the first date larger than the one in ColB

Comment: Hello, I have revised the answer with a new formula.

Comment: One more question jenn; if there are dates before so for example Fred had a date of 6/1/2017 in column F. From trials in excel it pulls the closest value not the next highest value so is there a way to exclude value lower than the value in column B?

Comment: I have revised the answer to exclude values equal to or lesser than the value in column B.